# Replace column with data from other columns

Tags: sql

Looking to update a column with data from other existing columns in the same table.

Example of my current data:

```
ID            DOB     FirstName     LastName    Gender
1x2v3b4n5m  19560809    John          Doe         M
```

What I'm looking to do is Replace the ID = DOB, first 3 char FirstName, first 3 char LastName, and Gender

```
ID
19560809JOHDOEM
```

Thanks in advance, this is stumping me.

Comment: Hint:  `CONCAT()`, `LET()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
asuming DOB type is varchar()

```
UPDATE TableName
SET ID = DOB + LEFT(FirstName,3) + LEFT(LastName,3) + Gender
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update t 
SET t.id = CAST(DOB AS VARCHAR(20)) + LEFT(FirstName,3) + LEFT(LastName,3) + Gender
from testtbl t
```

Or

```
Update t 
SET t.id = CONCAT(CAST(DOB AS VARCHAR(20)), LEFT(FirstName,3), LEFT(LastName,3) ,Gender)
from testtbl t
```